# Search for a title in LDAP using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ldap

I'm trying to search for a user's title in LDAP using C#.

My current search is this, in which I'm trying to search for a Janitor named John Smith:

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact)(|(sn=Smith)(givenname=John)(title=Janitor)))";
```

It's not working though.

Can anyone point me to where I'm going wrong? I know I've got the `sn` and `givenname` portion correct as that part works .. . but the title filter isn't .

Comment: Could it be that you need objectClass=user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What LDAP server are you using ?

On CentOs DS, this one works :

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(sn=Smith)(givenname=John)(title=Janitor))";
```

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because that `Title` attribute is really called `personalTitle` in LDAP.

Try this search filter instead:

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=contact)(|(sn=Smith)(givenname=John)(personalTitle=Janitor)))";
```

Active Directory MVP Richard Mueller has a great site with invaluable information on how to use AD from .NET - [find his references documents (Excel sheets) here](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) - download them, use them - enjoy!